# Scala - Vector contains (types comparison)

Tags: scala, vector, contains

I'm trying to check in a Vector of "paths" which ones contain all the stops wanted. I already created a function that gives all the paths that have a given stop.

```
    def pathIncludesPoint(pathList: PathList, stopWanted: Point): Option[Vector[Path]] = {

     if (pathList.paths.isEmpty) None

     else Some(

       for {
         path <- pathList.paths
         stop <- path.stops
         if stop.contains(stopWanted)
       } yield path)

    }

   def pathIncludesListOfPoint(pathList: PathList, stopsWanted: Vector[Point]): Option[Vector[Path]] = {

      if (pathList.paths.isEmpty) None

      else Some(

        pathList.paths.filter(path => stopsWanted.forall(stopWanted => pathIncludesPoint(pathList, stopWanted).contains(path)))

      )

   }
```

I'm trying to check if the Vector contains the path wanted :

```
pathList.paths.filter(path => stopsWanted.forall(stopWanted => pathIncludesPoint(pathList, stopWanted).contains(path)))
```

but the last path return an error because I'm comparing a Vector[Path] (what returns the function "pathIncludesPoint") and a Path. I don't understand using the scala Library my error.

Thanks!

Here is the structure of Path and PathList if needed :

```
case class Path(segments: Vector[Segment]) {

  def stops: Option[Vector[Point]] = {

    if (segments.isEmpty) None

    else Some({

      for {
        segment <- segments
      } yield segment.from

     }.tail)}

}



case class PathList(paths: Vector[Path]) {

}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks ! using the {} button and copy past the code in didn't work properly but selecting the code and then using the button did

Comment: can you please add the error?

Comment: done both, thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because `pathIncludesPoint(pathList, stopWanted)` has type `Option[Vector[Path]]`, so your `.contains(path)` is actually working on the `Option`, not on the `Vector`.

To fix this, maybe you can drop some uses of `Option` and just return an empty `Vector` where you currently return `None`?

Or if you want to keep all uses of `Option` and just want to fix the line with the `.contains`, you can use `.exists` as follows:

```
pathIncludesPoint(pathList, stopWanted).exists(_.contains(path))
```

Here, the `.exists` handles the `Option` and the `.contains` handles the `Vector`.